# Regex multiline option is not recognized by access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the a **myRegex** function to extract Regexes from a string. When I run a query that uses the function I get the following error on multiline.

> Method or data member not found.

**This is the regex Function:**

```
Function myRegex(ByRef myString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
   Dim rgx As New RegExp
    Dim colMatches As MatchCollection
    With rgx
        .pattern = pattern
        .ignoreCase = True
        .Global = False
        .Multiline = False
        Set colMatches = .Execute(myString)
    End With
    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        myRegex = colMatches(0).Value
    Else
        myRegex = ""
    End If
End Function
```

**This is the query I used:**

```
SELECT myRegex(phone,"[0-9]+")
FROM table1
```

**I have the following reference libraries checked:**

- Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 1.0
- Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following line

```
Dim rgx As New RegExp
```

...matches `RegExp` with the first library that defines that Class, which is

```
Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 1.0
```

This is an older version that does not support the `Multiline` property. You need the `RegExp` class from:

```
Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
```

So either:

- Remove the link with that older 1.0 reference library, or
- Qualify the `RegExp` class as `VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp`, or
- Use late binding (slower), with `CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")`

Answer (score 2):

You can uncheck the first VBScript Regular Expressions reference ... the 1.0 version ... as [@trincot suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080790/77335).

Or you could uncheck both references and use late binding:

```vb
'Dim rgx As New RegExp
Dim rgx As Object
Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
```

However, since your query will call the function repeatedly, you may notice better performance with a `Static` object variable.

```vb
Function myRegex(ByRef myString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As String
    Static rgx As Object
    Dim colMatches As Object

    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        ' create the RegExp object just once
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With rgx
            .ignoreCase = True
            .Global = False
            .Multiline = False
        End With
    End If
    rgx.pattern = pattern
    Set colMatches = rgx.Execute(myString)

    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        myRegex = colMatches(0).Value
    Else
        myRegex = ""
    End If
End Function
```